# ProcessBuilder for linux

Tags: java, linux, adb, cross-platform, processbuilder

i have the following code which executes shell commands and returns the output. This works fine on windows but does not work on linux.

```
public class devicedata 
{
public static String pda;
public static String csc;
public static String salescode;
public static String model;
public static String countrycode;


    public static void ddata() throws IOException 
    {
        ProcessBuilder process5 = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell","getprop","ro.product.model");   
        Process p1 = process5.start();
        InputStream stdin1 = p1.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader writer1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdin1));         
        model=writer1.readLine();



        ProcessBuilder process6 = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell","getprop","ro.build.PDA");   
        Process p2 = process6.start();
        InputStream stdin2 = p2.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader writer2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdin2));         
        pda=writer2.readLine();

        ProcessBuilder process7 = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell","getprop","ril.official_cscver");   
        Process p3 = process7.start();
        InputStream stdin3 = p3.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader writer3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdin3));
        csc=writer3.readLine();

        ProcessBuilder process8 = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell","getprop","ro.csc.sales_code");   
        Process p4 = process8.start();
        InputStream stdin4 = p4.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader writer4 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdin4));
        salescode=writer4.readLine();

        ProcessBuilder process9 = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell","getprop","ro.csc.country_code");   
        Process p5 = process9.start();
        InputStream stdin5 = p5.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader writer5 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdin5));
        countrycode=writer5.readLine();
    }

}
```

What changes should i do to make this platform independent.

Edit:-
Error :- the constructor ProcessBuilder(String, String,String) is undefined

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: basically i made an executable jar which uses the value stored in the strings csc,pda,model etc and sets these value in a JTextField. It runs fine on windows, but when i run that jar file on Ubuntu, the values are not updated on the JTextField

Comment: I got the error. the constructor ProcessBuilder(String,String,String) is undefined . do i have to specify some path for the commands to execute ?